# How do I enlarge go.Choropleth's map when saving it?

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, choropleth

I have a code that generates a choropleth map of Texas using custom GeoJson and saves it with `plotly.write_image` (I use Orca as an engine).

```
import typing as t
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import json
JSON = t.Union[str, int, float, bool, None,
               t.Mapping[str, 'JSON'], t.List['JSON']]


def draw_map(districts: JSON,
             df: pd.DataFrame,
             name: str,
             height: int,
             width: int) -> None:
    colorscale = [[0, '#D40000'],
                 [0.05789804908747634, '#D40000'],
                 [0.11705475141598479, '#CC2F4A'],
                 [0.12146003775959714, '#CC2F4A'],
                 [0.13089993706733785, '#E27F90'],
                 [0.18628067967275005, '#E27F90'],
                 [0.18753933291378216, '#F2B3BE'],
                 [0.18753933291378216, '#F2B3BE'],
                 [0.8193832599118943, '#86B6F2'],
                 [0.8445563247325362, '#86B6F2'],
                 [0.9030837004405287, '#4389E3'],
                 [0.9282567652611706, '#4389E3'],
                 [0.9616110761485211, '#1666CB'],
                 [1.0, '#1666CB']]
    fig = go.Figure(data=go.Choropleth(
        geojson=districts,
        locations=df["District"],
        z=df["Result"],
        colorscale=colorscale,
        showscale=False))
    fig.update_traces(marker_line_color="white",
                      marker_line_width=1)
    fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations",
                    projection_type="natural earth",
                    visible=False,
                    bgcolor="#D7EAE2")
    fig.layout.paper_bgcolor = "#D7EAE2"
    fig.layout.plot_bgcolor = "#D7EAE2"
    fig.update_layout(margin_t=0, margin_b=0,
                      margin_l=0, margin_r=0)
    fig.write_image(name, width=width, height=height)
    return fig


def main() -> None:
    with open("districts.json") as file:
        districts = json.load(file)
    df = pd.read_csv("texas.csv", index_col=0)
    fig = draw_map(districts, df, "TX-20-pres-districts.png", 750, 750)
```

The end result looks like this:

[image]

I would like the map itself to be bigger, while keeping the quality and the resolution (750x750) intact. How could I do it?